# What is $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x}{x-1}$?

Tags: limits, infinity

I want to calculate the limit
$$
\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{x}{x-1}.
$$
I know that this can be achieved using l'Hospital but cannot figure out how to do this.

Comment: $$\dfrac x{x-1}=\dfrac1{1-\dfrac1x}$$

Comment: how could it possible you  "cannot figure out how to do this"? if you know l'Hospital? $x'=(x-1)'=1$

Comment: L'hopital just tells you to differentiate the numerator and denominator ... Just do that and you have your answer

Comment: Did you even make an attempt at solving the problem? You say you know you can use l'Hospital... well... **did you** use it? What was the result?

Answer (score 4):

Like  lab bhattacharjee said:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\frac{x}{x}}{\frac{x}{x}-\frac{1}{x}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{x}}=$$
$$\frac{1}{1-\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}}=\frac{1}{1-0}=\frac{1}{1}=1$$

Comment: You forgot this step at the end of the first line: $\frac{1}{1-\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}}$

Comment: @barakmanos What you want :0

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x-1+1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to\infty}1+ \frac{1}{x-1}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use L'Hospital: it's a *high school theorem* that the limit at $\infty$ of a rational function is the limit of the ratio  of the highest degree terms of its numerator and  denominator.

Comment: Not all high schools have calculus

Comment: What's a high school theorem?

Comment: @Eric S. A theorem that many people see during their secondary education

Comment: @BCLC: Here when they take mathematics, they see this kind of theorems.